# KML Balloon formatting and overall display issues

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, balloon

I have set up a KML Tour in GE with default balloon and text styling. The balloons and text and display fine.

However on my computer (Macbook pro retina both osx and win 7) the balloons are rectangular rather than rounded.

These images show the difference in rendering.

[image: Rounded balloon]

[image: Rectangular balloon]

I have tried deleting cache, update drivers, deleting and re-adding the plugin, deleting and re-adding Google Earth, pretty much everything I can think of other than deleting windows and re-installing which seems overkill to me :).

Any help, wisdom or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Are the two images of the Earth plugin on different machines/browser, or is one of the full Google Earth application and one of the plugin on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the Google Earth plugin doesn't render balloons in the same way as the full desktop application (if that is what you are asking).

The rectangular, non rounded, balloons are the default for the Google Earth plugin.